# CSS star rating separation

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good night.

Hello guys, I have a question: I have a Radio Button Star Rating Widget in my page, at the moment the stars are close to each other and I need to separate them (fill the div's witdh).

**HTML**

```
<div class="stars-div">
    <div class="stars">
        <input class="star-input star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-5" for="star-5"></label>                                   
        <input class="star-input star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-4" for="star-4"></label>
        <input class="star-input star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-3" for="star-3"></label>
        <input class="star-input star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-2" for="star-2"></label>
        <input class="star-input star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-1" for="star-1"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.stars-div {
    padding-top: 9.8%;
    padding-left: 5%
}


.stars {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%
}

.star-input { 
    display: none; 
}

.star-icon {
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.star-input:checked ~ .star-icon:before {
    content: '\f005';
    color: #FD4;
}

.star-icon:hover:before, .star-icon:hover ~ .star-icon:before {
    content: '\f005';
    color: #ffea8e;
}

.star-icon:before {
    content: '\f006';
    font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

**NOTE:** When I try to use Bootstrap Grid or to use any div tag around an input only one star will be filled.

What can I do to fix this ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**see here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/bssfusgn/)**

just divide the div into 5 sections ( you have 5 stars )

for the other issue ( with star filled ) can you give me an example ?

code :

```
.star-icon {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 50px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width:20%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. PD: The problem with the filled is that if I use this for example <div> <star.input1> <star.label1></div>, i wont fill the stars before the one I am clicking but with yourhelp it is working as I need

Answer (score 0):

You have to make that stars block in the one div so that it will work in all devices.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="stars-div">
      <div class="stars">
        <input class="star-input star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-5" for="star-5"></label>                                   
        <input class="star-input star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-4" for="star-4"></label>
        <input class="star-input star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-3" for="star-3"></label>
        <input class="star-input star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-2" for="star-2"></label>
        <input class="star-input star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star"/>
        <label class="star-icon star-1" for="star-1"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.stars-div {
  padding-top: 9.8%;
  padding-left: 1%
 }


.stars {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%
}

.star-input { 
  display: none; 
}

.star-icon {
  float: right;
  padding: 1%;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.star-input:checked ~ .star-icon:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #FD4;
}

.star-icon:hover:before, .star-icon:hover ~ .star-icon:before {
     content: '\f005';
     color: #ffea8e;
}

.star-icon:before {
  content: '\f006';
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```